# Javascript if else help for handler

Tags: javascript

Now the form is one form, here is the new broken code

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function verifyIt(){
    if((document.form1.baseline_08.value != "" && Number(document.form1.baseline_08.value) &&  document.form1.baseline_08.value != "-1")){
    if((document.form1.baseline_09.value != "" && Number(document.form1.baseline_09.value) &&  document.form1.baseline_09.value != "-1")){
        document.form1.submit();
        return true;
    }else{
        alert("Please select how old you were when you started smoking every day.");
        return false;
    }
}
function submit2(){
    document.form1.direction.value = "back";
    document.form1.submit();
}

</script>
```

Now the verify doesnt work at all. I just dont see what is wrong with this now.

The problem I am having is the form1 is the only one being recognized. I believe it is because of my if statement structure. Basicly I only get the return from the form1. What is wrong with my js?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to submit two separate forms that way. You can do it with XMLHttpRequest (ajax) but not this way. The other problem is that your first `if else` always returns from the function, with either `true` or `false`.  Once you return from the function the rest of it won't be evaluated.

Comment: You can't submit two separate forms simultaneously.

Comment: I should note, I didnt write the js, I just had to consolidate a bunch of forms on the same page, making me push together all the pages verifications.

Comment: So then should I create separate verifications for each form on the same page?

Answer (score 1):

> I believe it is because of my if statement structure.

Yes, you are always `return`ing after checking `form1`. However, you cannot submit multiple forms at a time, so you should combine them into one. Then use

```
function verifyIt() {
    if(!(document.form.baseline_08.value == "" && Number(document.form.baseline_08.value) &&  document.form.baseline_08.value != "-1")){
        alert("Please select how old you were when you started smoking every day.");
        return false;
    }
    if(!(document.form.baseline_09.value != "" && Number(document.form.baseline_09.value) &&  document.form.baseline_09.value != "-1")){
        alert("Please select when you would smoke after waking up.");
        return false;
    }
    document.form.submit();
}
```

Comment: I suppose I Will try this then.

Comment: Is there anything more like an "and" type of statement to submit multiple forms tether?

Comment: No, you can only submit one form at once